# Scraping data on AWS EC2 using crontab: output missing in log file

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, cron

I'm scraping a large amount of data from the web using crontab on an AWS EC2 instance. The script scrapes thousands of webpages and prints "*webpageID* done" after each one. Because I'm scheduling the script to run and then logging out of the instance, I'm saving the stdout output to a log file using the following command on crontab:

```
0 19 26 10 * /home/ec2-user/scrape.sh &>> /home/ec2-user/output.log
```

The script crashed after scraping 10,000 webpages but for some reason output.log stopped printing "*webpageID* done" after 8,000 webpages. The last few lines in output.log look something like this:

```
7998: webpage 012345 done
7999: webpage 012346 done
8000: webpage 012347 d
```

So it stopped printing midway but the script continued to scrape another 2000 webpages. Why could this be happening? Is there a better way of saving your output while being logged out of an EC2 instance (ie. without keeping an SSH pipe open)?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your crontab

```
0 19 26 10 * /home/ec2-user/scrape.sh &>> /home/ec2-user/output.log 2>&1
```

Also, be aware that if your script is in `Bash` then don't forget to set it in your `cron` (**IF** you are using `cron`)

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Comment: What will the ```2>&1``` do exactly? The print statements are showing up in the log file, they're just not complete. Also, my shell script already starts with ```#!/bin/bash```.